# QTip v 2.2.1 not showing with Bootstrap v 3.3

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, qtip2, imagemapster

I am using Bootstrap v3.3 with 
Jquery v2.0.3,
Jquery-Migrate v1.2.1,
Jquery.Imagemapster v 1.2.14,
Modernizr v2.8.3 
and Qtip v2.2.1

Normally, in a simple HTML page Qtip show perfectly on the each map area as desire but not showing when I paste that simple code in the bootstrap framework.

```
<script>
(function ($) { 
    jQuery('area[alt]').qtip( { content: { attr: 'alt' }, style: { classes: 'qtip-youtube'} 
}); 

    jQuery('.field-item img').each(function() { 
        jQuery(this).qtip({ style: { classes: 'qtip-youtube'}, content : jQuery(this).attr('alt') 
    }); 

}); 

})(jQuery);
```

I haven't no idea what I am doing wrong?
Kindly Advice me soon.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

```
(function ($) { 
  $('area\\[alt\\]').qtip( { content: { attr: 'alt' }, style: { classes: 'qtip-youtube'} }); 
  $('.field-item img').each(function() { 
    $(this).qtip({ style: { classes: 'qtip-youtube'}, content : $(this).attr('alt') }); 
  });
})(jQuery);
```

updated, could you please try again? thanks.

Comment: No still not... what I a missing? Qtip is working perfectly in a simple HTML page but when I pasted the same code on the bootstrap and all script based main page QTip disappears.. may be something conflict somewhere on the page or what?

Comment: Hey Ma, could you please try again?